Could not write cache value to 'C:\Users\office\.gradle\daemon\7.3.3\registry.bin'
when gradlew clean or assemble build then comes this issue
successfully gradlew clean and create assemble Release build.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
react native projects

What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Check JVM Options: Make sure there are no unrecognized JVM options in your Gradle configuration. Check any scripts or environment variables that might be setting JVM options for Gradle.

Update Gradle Version: Ensure you are using a compatible Gradle version with your project. Sometimes upgrading or downgrading Gradle can resolve compatibility issues.
Configure Daemon Settings: If you have specific daemon settings, you can try configuring them in your gradle.properties file. For example, you can set org.gradle.daemon=true to enable the daemon or org.gradle.daemon.max.idle-time=600000 to set the maximum idle time in milliseconds.
Check System Resources: Ensure your system has enough resources (memory, CPU) available to start the Gradle daemon. Sometimes, resource constraints can prevent the daemon from starting.
Restart System: If none of the above steps work, try restarting your system. This can sometimes resolve issues related to system configuration or resource allocation.
If the issue persists, you may need to provide more details about your Gradle configuration and environment to diagnose the problem further.
